# error in android simple button program

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android so bear with me...

I am receiving an error in android studio when i try to run my program in an emulator
I am trying to have a button that plays a button sound..... pretty simple right...

here is the logcat

```
Process: com.myApp.soundboard, PID: 1046
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myApp.soundboard/com.myApp.soundboard.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:844)
        at com.myApp.soundboard.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:19)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is the code from the main

```
 import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    final MediaPlayer mp_imageButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button7 );

    public void imageButtonOnClick(View v)
    {
        Button imageButton = (Button) v;
        ((Button) v).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                mp_imageButtonClick.start();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    }
```

any thoughts says its caused by a null pointer exception probably simple for someone who knows what they are doing

Comment: It also looks like you are setting the Button's `OnClickListener` in an `android:onclick` callback. If you define an onclick callback in XML, you don't need to set an `OnClickListener` in your code.

Comment: your right good observation

Answer (score 1):

Move this

```
 final MediaPlayer mp_imageButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button7 );
```

in `onCreate`

```
MediaPlayer mp_imageButtonClick;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp_imageButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button7 );
```

Also Change to

```
public void imageButtonOnClick(View v)
{

      mp_imageButtonClick.start();  

}
```

if you have

```
 android:onClick:"imageButtonClick"
```

for button in xml

Comment: this fixed it.... thanks, and i learned something... now to trudge on... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
final MediaPlayer mp_imageButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button7 );
```

This line is using the 'this' reference before you have created an object. Since you have not yet created an object, the 'this' keyword references nothing, and you get a null pointer value. If you move this line into your onCreate() method you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this (MainActivity) before it has been fully initialized by the system, which causes the crash because MediaPlayer.create is trying to use the Activity as Context.

You can ensure your Activity has been fully created by using the onCreate callback :

First declare your MediaPlayer variable :

```
private MediaPlayer mp_imageButtonClick;
```

then move the rest of the call to onCreate :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp_imageButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button7 ); 
}
```